# Get count occurrence with the date filtering

Tags: php, mysql, count

Hello I have this table

```
table name : addresses


|  id  |branch |      datetime      |
____________________________________

|16875 |north  | 2015-07-13 02:11:34|
|16345 |north  | 2015-07-11 08:04:42|
|16000 |north  |2015-07-10 08:16:07 |
|16960 |north  |2015-07-13 05:16:04 |
|15909 |north  |2015-07-10 05:16:05 |
|16669 |south  |2015-07-12 07:16:03 |
|16513 |south  |2015-07-12 00:20:43 |
|16699 |south  |2015-07-12 08:16:02 |
|15939 |east   |2015-07-10 06:16:05 |
|16449 |east   |2015-07-11 11:16:04 |
|16517 |east   |2015-07-12 01:16:01 |
|16729 |east   |2015-07-12 09:16:02 |
|16418 |west   |2015-07-11 10:18:16 |
|15971 |west   |2015-07-10 07:16:04 |
|16785 |west   |2015-07-12 11:16:01 |
|16757 |west   |2015-07-12 10:16:02 |
|16353 |west   |2015-07-11 08:16:04 |
|16877 |west   |2015-07-13 02:16:03 |
```

On my php page i want to query this table but only show the count of the duplicate values since i have datetime column I want to pick date and show the duplicate value on that date.

for example is I pick date

**2015-07-13**

So I it will query

```
|Branch|count|
______________
|north |  2  |
|west  |  1  |
______________
```

another example is I want to pick date is

**2015-07-10**
It will query

```
|Branch|count|
______________
|north |  2  |
|east  |  1  |
|west  |  1  |
______________
```

on my php page I use this code

```
   <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" id="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><h3>Branch</h3></th>
                <th><h3>Count</h3></th>



            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php
// Connect to database server
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "user") or die (mysql_error ());

// Select database
mysql_select_db("data") or die(mysql_error());

// SQL query
$strSQL  = "SELECT branch,count(branch) as occurence FROM `addresses` WHERE datetime >= \"2015-07-10\" AND datetime < \"2015-07-11\" group by branch";

// Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {

   // W
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"<td>". $row['branch'];
    echo"<td>". $row['occurence'];





  }

// Close the database connection
mysql_close();
                    ?>
```

and my output is

```
|Branch|count|
______________
|north |  2  |
|east  |  1  |
|west  |  1  |
______________
```

So how can I integrate the date filtering on my php page? that count the duplicate values.

Thank You

Comment: Really did not clear your question what you want?

Comment: Hi sorry if you don't get my question actually I already count the values have a same value on the datetime of range i want using sql query.

but i want is to set date in time using my php page.

Comment: @CarlvicJapitanaLim How about my answer? Does it help?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `from` and `to` date as parameters to the query:

```
// Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'user', 'password');

// Prepare statement
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT branch, count(branch) AS occurence
                        FROM `addresses`
                        WHERE datetime >= :from AND datetime < :to
                        GROUP BY branch");

// Bind parameters
$stmt->bindParam(':from', $from);
$stmt->bindParam(':to',   $to);

// Execute
$from = '2015-07-10';
$to   = '2015-07-11';
$stmt->execute();

// Fetch result
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

See the [PHP documentation on Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for more information.

Comment: Hi i try this code but it shows an error 

    Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: I modified my answer, set `$from` and `$to` outside of `bindParam()`.